# Palandrome-ish code

Tags: popularity-contest, polyglot

Create a program that does the same thing forwards and backwards, in **different languages**. “Different languages” does not include different versions of the same language.

### Challenge

This program can take any input and write anything to stdout and stderr.
However, the program must output *exactly the same* things for the same input when run backwards in the other language. This explicitly includes anything written to stderr **while the program is running**, including errors. The length of the output from stdout and stderr must sum to at least 5. The minimum program length is 2 bytes.

- This is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the answer with the most votes wins.
- Comments are allowed, however the commented text must take up less than ¼ of the total program.

Comment: This is too broad because there is no real objective for the code, or criteria for judging one program better than another.

Comment: Also, changing it to code-golf is no good because `1` would be valid in numerous languages. BTW, "derivative language" is not well defined at all.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies should I remove that?

Comment: @ETHproductions The challenge is making it do the same thing. I have also removed the derivative languages stipulation.

Comment: Would comments and programs that crash with errors be allowed?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Yes and Yes. However, the errors must be *exactly the same*.

Answer (score 4):

## BF + Foo

You saw it coming

```
-[------->+<]>-.-[->+++++<]>++.+++++++..+++."olleH"
```